# Angularjs REST API Interaction failure

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am a Angularjs New bee.This is my first Angularjs application, i am just trying to interact with Nodejs service call and to print the response. But I am receiving different error in Chrome and Firefox.

In chrome i got uncaught error and in firefox i got Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Here is my coding:
index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>Monitoring</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js">
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-resource.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="CommonMetricsCtrl">
        {{data}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

controller.js

```
var App = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
App.controller('CommonMetricsCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource',
    function($scope, $resource) {

        function createResource(url) {
            return $resource(url + '?alt=:alt&method=:callback', {
                alt: 'json',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }, {
                get: {
                    method: 'JSONP',
                    headers: [{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }, {
                        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
                    }]
                },
                isArray: false
            });
        }

        URL = "http://localhost:1111/servicelist";

        var resource = createResource(URL);

        resource.get({}, function processResponse(response) {

            console.log(response);
            $scope.data = response;
            if (response.error) {
                console.log('Error here');
            }

        });

    }
]);
```

I dont know where i went wrong, Can any one sort out the issue please?

Comment: `myapp !== myApp`. Modules and controllers are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, thats just the typo error @Ben Fortune. Dint get the response from the service yet

Comment: here I have add plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/GeKIqxU2VJekCodoY3yF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the angular-route module twice.